# Microsoft-graph-client doesn’t open popup-login

Tags: next.js, microsoft-graph-api

I am using microsoft-graph-client in a nextjs application.

When logging-in, the Microsoft login always opens in a new tab. This is annoying for the user, and I would like it to use popup instead. However, setting loginStyle: 'popup' has no effect. It still opens a new tab each time.

Any suggestions of what may cause this?

```
import { Client } from '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client';
import { TokenCredentialAuthenticationProvider} from '@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client/authProviders/azureTokenCredentials';

const clientId = process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID;
const clientSecret = process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_SECRET;
const tenantId = process.env.AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID;

       const credential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential({
        tenantId: tenantId,
        clientId: clientId,       
        loginStyle: 'popup'
      });

      const authProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthenticationProvider(credential, {
        scopes: ['User.Read Files.Read'],
      });
      
      const graphClient = Client.initWithMiddleware({ authProvider: authProvider });
```